# Widget Cross Thread GUI update

Tags: c++, c++11, widget

How can I implemante the following in Widget?
I want to update GUI in a detached background thread.
c++ language

Comment: wxWidget, not widget.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to look around at successful questions. Yours is a bit short of detail, and we expect to see some prior effort, such as the code of what you've already got.

Comment: Hi, quoting from wxWidgets documentation on http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_thread.html "When writing a multi-threaded application, it is strongly recommended that no secondary threads call GUI functions. The design which uses one GUI thread and several worker threads which communicate with the main one using events is much more robust"